# React app can't load css in windows server 2019

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, windows-server-2019

When I run react app on my local machine(windows 10), it works fine. But in windows server 2019 when I run my code (npm install then npm start). Project page just shows html not css. Also, there is no error in chrome network tab or in the console

[image]

Comment: you say there's no error, so chrome is claiming to have loaded the css file linked, or chrome doesn't try it's not linked?

Comment: What does it mean linked? @TZHX

Comment: I added linked to index.html                                                                                  ```<link rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
        <link id="theme-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/theme/indigo/theme-light.css" />
        <link id="layout-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/layout/css/layout-light.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/pages/primeflex.min.css">```